# Broken Laptop with esata connection

Tags: hard-drive

My Laptop broke so I have purchased a new Laptop. I would like to transfer photos etc over to the new laptop and believe I can do this by removing the hard drive and connecting a powered sata cable between the two laptops. However I notice that my old laptop already has an external esata connection so can I use this or do I need to physically remove the hard drive?

Comment: You need to remove the hdd from the old laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the hard drive. eSata is a input, not output - you can connect drives to it, but not use it to read from hard drive. By the way, if you could, it would be a major security issue.